# How to Create an Array using Recursion While Specifying the Min & Max Values in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, recursion

Here is the challenge:

We have defined a function named rangeOfNumbers with two parameters. The function should return an array of integers which begins with a number represented by the startNum parameter and ends with a number represented by the endNum parameter. The starting number will always be less than or equal to the ending number. Your function must use recursion by calling itself and not use loops of any kind. It should also work for cases where both startNum and endNum are the same.

```
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {

}
rangeOfNumbers(5, 10); //Should return [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Is there a simple, one line way of tackling this? I'm struggling with how to handle the base case and return the desired array with recursion.

Comment: If you want to do it in one line, use the ternary `condition ? true-value : false-value` operator. The condition should test for the base case; one value is the base value, the other recurses.

Comment: Is the recursion required? I could see a simple solution with `Array.from({ length: max - min }, (_, i) => I + min)`

Comment: Recursion is required for this challenge

Comment: base-case would most likely be when startNum === endNum

Comment: I considered startNum === endNum but my challenge is returning the desired array when I go through some recursive iterations.

Comment: If it is returning the desired array then what is the issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function rangeOfNumbers(startNum, endNum) {
  return startNum <= endNum ? [startNum].concat(rangeOfNumbers(startNum+1, endNum)) : []
}
console.log(rangeOfNumbers(5, 10));
```

Comment: Concat was a great idea for this challenge, this is a very elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way using spread syntax -

```js
const range = (a, b) =>
  a > b
    ? []
    : [ a, ...range(a + 1, b) ]
    
console.log(range(1, 5))
// [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

console.log(range(3, 6))
// [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

console.log(range(9, 3))
// []
```